# can linux be host of a windows docker image?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, image, host

I am a completely beginner in Docker technology.
My company uses linux nodes as gitlab runners.
These gitlab runners as part of the CI/CD normally build a docker image to build and deploy java applications.
My application is an exception : is written in c# .net framework 4.8 so my idea was to use a windows server core base image to build the source code.
Do we need to have an additional gitlab runner with windows OS on it so it can run the image to compile the code?
Or is linux able to run windows images as well?
(I never used linux : ))

I just tried building and running the image on my windows notebook.

Comment: Q: Can Linux be the host of a Windows Docker container? Sure! I just ran a .NET 7 Docker container on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance in the cloud earlier this afternoon.  Can you run a *COMPLETE* Windows 11 desktop, or Windows Server 2019 OS in a Docker container - no.  But a broad spectrum of essentially "windows apps" *ARE* supported for Docker containers on a Linux host.  It all depends on exactly what you need.  Look here for more details: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/